# BASH let command..gives wrong result on padded numbers

Tags: bash, command, let

The following code prints 4 as expected:

```
let x=21
let x=$x-1
echo $x
```

But the following prints 16:

```
let x=000021
let x=$x-1
echo $x
```

Could someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

00021 is an octal constant. The output 16 is the correct decimal result.
To get the octal value use

```
printf "%o\n" $x
```

Remove the leading zeros if the number is decimal.